# Can I use nginx and GnuTLS together?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I read that nginx works with OpenSSL. But since GnuTLS is the only software that provides TLS 1.2 support, it would be useful to combine that.

So, how can I compile nginx with GnuTLS on Ubuntu? =)

Comment: I dont think that nginx has TLS support.  After searching their wiki, I have found nothing that suggests that it supports TLS at this time.  You could consider making a feature request on their site.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use GnuTLS with nginx. Here are some source files having `ssl` in their names (from the [nginx 1.7.7 source](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/file/7d7eac6e31df)), GnuTLS does not seem to be mentioned:

```
auto/lib/openssl/
src/mail/ngx_mail_ssl_module.h
src/mail/ngx_mail_ssl_module.c
src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.c
src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.h
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.h
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c
src/event/ngx_event_openssl_stapling.c
```

Neither has GnuTLS been mentioned in the source (`grep -rni gnutls .` or even `grep -rni gnu .`). According to [Compatibility with the OpenSSL Library](http://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Compatibility-with-the-OpenSSL-library.html), GnuTLS cannot fully replace OpenSSL.

Unless you really need it, use the current version of nginx and OpenSSL. Work has been done for OpenSSL 1.0.1 to support TLS 1.2. See [*Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1  [14 Mar 2012]*](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html).

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: OpenSSL 1.0.1 beta adds TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support.